# ios UIWebview external iframe sometimes not loaded

Tags: ios, iframe, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView that holds an extrenal iframe (for youtube and vimeo)
Sometimes it just doesn't load.

When going back and rerendering the view - it does load

Did anyone encounter the issue?

Iframe example:

```
NSString *htmlStr = @"<html><head><title>.</title><style>body,html,iframe{margin:0;padding:0; background-color: rgb(233,229,229);}</style></head><body><iframe src=\"http://player.vimeo.com/video/52600303\" width=\"320\" height=\"170\" frameborder=\"0\" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>";
[cell.externalVideoWebview loadHTMLString:htmlStr baseURL:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it is in the vimeo documentation, in iOS `webkitallowfullscreen` and `mozallowfullscreen` are not needed - and maybe even harmful because when I removed those - the issue is solved (and the iframe loads much faster)